# SFTP Passwordless connection

Tags: passwords, sftp

there is sftp user for which password less connectivity is established long back however we are trying to connect from other sources\server and I forgot the passwd of the user so if I reset the password will it affect the existing passwordless connectivity ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't affect passwordless connectivity because you're using public keys authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Usually passwordless authorisation uses ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. So, if you have a private key and its pub key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (it's already in, if you can log in now) then you can do with the password whatever you like.

Of course there are other storages for authorized_keys.